# How to `impl Clone for` a type that must not be allowed to move?

Tags: rust

I'm wrapping objects from a C library that generates events on the object. In order to map the low-level event to the high-level one, I need to pass the address of the high-level object.

This all works.

```
mod c
{
    enum Pen; // opaque struct
}

struct Pen
{
    pen: *mut c::Pen,
    event_hook: Option<Box<FnMut<(&mut Pen, EventDetails), ()>>>,
}

impl Pen
{
    fn new() -> Box<Pen>
    {
        let rv = box Pen{pen: ..., event_hook: None};
        ... set up hook to use rv's raw address in a callback and forward to event_hook ...;
        rv
    }
}

impl Drop for Pen
{
    fn drop(&mut self)
    {
        ...;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to `impl Clone`. I can't `impl Clone for Box<Pen>` because that conflicts with the implementation in liballoc. I can't `impl Clone for Pen` because the address would change after I set up the low-level hooks.

The ability to clone this type is rather important. I could `impl Pen` to give functions *named* `.clone()` and `.clone_from()` that actually return boxes, but that would prevent anyone from passing this object to a function that requires `<T: Clone>`

Comment: It is probably better to have the high-level `Pen` store the `Box` internally; as it stands, one can write `let x = Pen::new(); let y = *x;` to move the `Pen` in memory.

Comment: @dbaupp but then the Rust callback won't have access to any of the functions on `Pen`.

Comment: Hm, if you have `Pen { p: Box<InternalPen> }` I think you can expose `&InternalPen` safely (if `InternalPen` is affine), but even exposing `&mut InternalPen` is unsafe: someone could call `swap` to exchange two `InternalPen`s. As soon as you start exposing location-dependent values mutably externally it's hard to maintain safety. That is, it would be ok to have `FnMut<(&InternalPen, EventDetails), ()>`. If you're OK with having the risk of memory unsafety, then exposing `&mut InternalPen` is probably fine (it seems rare that people will call `swap` on such values).

Comment: Okay, so it turns out that I've talked to the maintainer of the upstream C library and he says not to bother with the event system for `Pen`s, it's going away in the next stable release. I still have the event system for `Term`s, but `Term` isn't `Clone` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the creation of your `Pen` struct from the hooking and de-hooking.

```
use std::kinds::marker::NoCopy;

mod c
{
    pub struct Pen; // opaque struct
}

struct Pen
{
    pen: *mut c::Pen,
    //event_hook: Option<Box<FnMut<(&mut Pen, EventDetails), ()>>>, // FIXME: this type does not compile
    _no_copy: NoCopy
}

struct PenHookInner {
    event_hook: Option<()> // TODO: maybe event_hook should move here from Pen?
}

struct PenHook<'a> {
    pen: &'a Pen,
    inner: PenHookInner,
}

impl Pen
{
    fn new() -> Pen
    {
        let rv = Pen { pen: 0 as *mut c::Pen /*, event_hook: None*/, _no_copy: NoCopy };
        rv
    }

    fn hook(&self) -> PenHook {
        // TODO: set up hook to use self.pen's raw address in a callback and forward to event_hook
        PenHook {
            pen: self,
            inner: PenHookInner { event_hook: None }
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for PenHookInner {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // TODO: remove the hook
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pen = Pen::new();
    let pen_hook = pen.hook();
    //drop(pen); //~ error: cannot move out of `pen` because it is borrowed
}
```

`Pen` contains a [`NoCopy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/kinds/marker/struct.NoCopy.html) field to make the struct not implicitly copyable. If you need to implement [`Drop`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) to free the "native" pen, then you don't need the `NoCopy` field. (Types that implement `Drop` are implicitly not `Copy`.)

When a `PenHook` is created, it borrows a reference to a `Pen`. This prevents the `Pen` from being moved or dropped while the `PenHook` exists. As long as the `PenHook` object exists, `Pen` can't be moved or dropped.

If `Pen` didn't have the `NoCopy` field, it could still be implicitly copied: remove it and you'll see that the `drop(pen);` line compiles. That's because `drop()` receives a copy of `pen` and drops that. Because `Pen` doesn't implement `Drop` in this sample, that's a no-op.

We now implement `Drop` for `PenHookInner`. `PenHookInner` would contain the data that is necessary to remove the hook. We can't implement `Drop` on `PenHook` directly without `#[unsafe_destructor]`, because of [issue 11406](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/11406). If we don't need to access the `pen` borrowed pointer in the implementation of `drop()`, then we can use a separate struct to work around it cleanly.

I made `Pen::new()` return a `Pen` rather than a `Box<Pen>`, because there's no reason to box the result. If the caller wants to box the value, they can use `box` at the call site.

...I was about to end with an open question about which type would implement `Clone`, but then I read your comment about `Pen` going away in the upstream library's next release. I suppose you wanted to clone both the pen and the hook. Obviously, with this structure, you wouldn't be able to do that easily. You'd be able to implement `Clone` on `Pen` easily, but for `PenHook`, you'd need something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `Pen` a [`NoCopy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/kinds/marker/struct.NoCopy.html) field that will prevent it from ever being implicitly copied.

Not sure if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: It can still be moved in memory, which will invalidate any internal pointers the object has to itself.